# C++ Verify the first input of two on the same line

Tags: c++, cin

```
string a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
if (a == "yes") break;
...
```

Why does this not work the way it looks like it should work? If the user enters "yes please" or "yes" the program should break out of whatever loop it's in, but that's not what happens. The console just prints a line feed and waits. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hint: You could open up a can of worms and use a [regular expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) here. You never know, it might just work.

Comment: The program will wait if you enter just "yes". It should not wait if you enter "yes please".

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

The read of the second string `b` is *not* optional, so if you enter `"yes"` or any other single word, the program blocks to let you enter the second one.

The flow of operations goes as follows:

- Wait for the first word into `a`
- Wait for the second word into `b`
- Compare the first word to `"yes"`

Note that the comparison does not start until the reading of `b` is over.

If you want to exit the loop on simple `"yes"`, read `a`, compare it to `"yes"`, break if necessary, and only then read `b`:

```
cin >> a;
if (a == "yes") break;
cin >> b;
```

Now if the loop does not exit you have both `a` and `b`, and you know that `a` is not equal to `"yes"`.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation

Answer (score 0):

Currently:

```
string a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
if (a == "yes") break;
...
```

The correct way of doing it would be as followed. b has no value when you cin a and b at the same time.

```
string a, b;
cin >> a;
if (a == "yes") 
{
break;
}
cin >> b;
```

b will still "be on the same line"